# No EC2 resource for EFS objects?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I noticed that the following fails

```
import boto3
boto3.resource('efs')
UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'efs'. Valid service names are: cloudformation, cloudwatch, dynamodb, ec2, glacier, iam, opsworks, s3, sns, sqs
```

Why is there no boto3 resource for EFS objects?

Comment: Documentation: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/efs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems EFS currently does not have a resource, you'll need to use the lower level client in the meanwhile.

```
client = boto3.client('efs')
```

You can probably expect support for EFS resource sometime in the future.

#### How to check

#### Available Clients - get_available_services()

```
>> s = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
>> s.get_available_services()
['acm', 'apigateway', 'application-autoscaling', 'autoscaling', 'cloudformation', 'cloudfront', 'cloudhsm', 'cloudsearch', 'cloudsearchdomain', 'cloudtrail', 'cloudwatch', 'codecommit', 'codedeploy', 'codepipeline', 'cognito-identity', 'cognito-idp', 'cognito-sync', 'config', 'datapipeline', 'devicefarm', 'directconnect', 'discovery', 'dms', 'ds', 'dynamodb', 'dynamodbstreams', 'ec2', 'ecr', 'ecs', 'efs', 'elasticache', 'elasticbeanstalk', 'elastictranscoder', 'elb', 'elbv2', 'emr', 'es', 'events', 'firehose', 'gamelift', 'glacier', 'iam', 'importexport', 'inspector', 'iot', 'iot-data', 'kinesis', 'kinesisanalytics', 'kms', 'lambda', 'logs', 'machinelearning', 'marketplacecommerceanalytics', 'meteringmarketplace', 'opsworks', 'rds', 'redshift', 'route53', 'route53domains', 's3', 'sdb', 'servicecatalog', 'ses', 'snowball', 'sns', 'sqs', 'ssm', 'storagegateway', 'sts', 'support', 'swf', 'waf', 'workspaces']
```

#### Available Resources - get_available_resources()

```
>> s = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
>> s.get_available_resources()
['cloudformation', 'cloudwatch', 'dynamodb', 'ec2', 'glacier', 'iam', 'opsworks', 's3', 'sns', 'sqs']
```